# Wet ceiling spots on a cold night but no rain

Tags: ceiling

We just moved a our new house here in Massachusetts. I moved this house 2 months ago so this our first winter. Today was while my wife was cooking, I noticed these random wet spots around the corner and it's not raining and it hasn't rained in a few days.

The crack in the picture was there before I moved here.  Currently its 15 f outside. I went into the attic and the attic is super cold. I couldn't really reach into the corner. What could cause these? I touched the spots and these feel somewhat wet. There is no water dripping or anything. My wife was doing some heavy cooking so I thought this maybe from the steam? What else could cause this? Thank you

[image]
[image]

Comment: The crack suggests there is or was a leak of some sort in this area. If you don't have any water pipes (perhaps drains, vents, or condensate lines) in your attic, there is likely a roof leak in this area. The recent appearance may be condensation of moisture that was present already from prior rains. What's above this ceiling? What part of the roof? Does the condensation continue along the entryway to the white paneled room? Is the paneled room a porch or other addition that has a joint with the roof over the beige room?

Comment: What is on the other side of the walls and above that ceiling is really what I am getting at - you might have some plumbing pipes going through that area - I see two different wall areas of the same ceiling I am guessing . I can not see this as condensate unless your attic was 15 degrees and you had no insulation above that ceiling.  Something is leaking - whether it is the roof or a pipe .. it is leaking. You said it has not rained in a few days (that would be about right for it to show up on the ceiling. Did it hail , note the date of the rain. See next comment..

Comment: You can check for hail damage - look for pock marks like golf ball size or smaller all over the shingles, look for missing granules in those areas and also in your gutters if you have them.

Comment: that's cooking steam condensing on a cold ceiling; add more insulation to the attic.